# Declare Syntax error in Mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax, declare

```
DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier
SET @id = NEWID()
```

When I try to use the above declare to set up unique identifier, I am getting the below error:

> DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier SET @id = NEWID()       Error Code: 1064.
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier SET @id = NEWID()'

Not sure what the issue is. Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The issue seems to be before the DECLARE already (MySQL error logging usually starts with the first character right after where things go wrong). So what is the rest of the code?

Comment: @Norbert Actually i am trying to create a  unique alphnumeric column in mysql. So i'm using the below query to do that. But when i execute the below query i get similar kind of error.  So i that first we need to use the declare function to achieve that but no luck

CREATE TABLE Product
(
 CustomerID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
   DEFAULT newid(),
 Company varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 ContactName varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
);

Comment: , ); – : There is a lost , after the NULL (if this gets nowhere: Edit your post to be more clear :) )

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation and adjust as needed:

- [9.4 User-Defined
  Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)
- [13.6.4 Variables in Stored
  Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-variables.html)
- [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)
  or
  [UUID_SHORT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short)

```sql
SET @`id` := UUID();
SELECT @`id`;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/7269)</kbd>